# Why does the camera image not appear in picamera?

Tags: pi-4, camera

I have a rPi4 using it with Pi cam 1.3.

Tried with

```
camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
sleep(5)
camera.capture('/tmp/picture.jpg')
camera.stop_preview()
```

but does not pop up anything, but the image is saved.

same with `raspistill`

What should I do to see the image of my cam?

Answer (score 0):

You may be either using VNC or SSH to connect to the Pi. If that's the case, you won't be able to see the image pop-up, and you now have two options to fix that.

1. Connecting the Pi to a monitor using HDMI
2. Turning on Direct Capture Mode on RPi's VNC server.

For option 2, connect to your Pi via VNC, open the VNC Server dialog, navigate Menu > Options > Troubleshooting, and select Enable direct capture mode. Finally, reconnect the VNC connection.

OR, if you're on the Pi with an HDMI-connected monitor, check which desktop driver you're using from `raspi-config` -> `Advanced Options` -> `GL-driver.` Then set the driver to G3 Legacy, if necessary.

Give us updates in the comments.

Comment: I'm on it with a directly connected monitor

Comment: Do you have KMS/OpenGL enabled? (set via `raspi-config` )
If it's either full or fake, change it back to legacy. The full KMS driver means ARM gets total control over the display pipeline, which prevents the GPU from adding the camera layers.

Comment: Nope, that not working also